# How are recurring contributions (standing orders) implemented in 4.7?

Tags: 4.7, recurring-contributions

I've read that recurring contributions are supported in core 4.7.   I can't figure out how this is done, and book.civicrm.org is still at 4.6 (or have I missed something?).  By recurring payments I mean, for example, monthly payments made from a contributor's bank.  In the UK this is done by what is known as a 'standing order'.  So, I don't mean recurring payments set up by a payment processor like Paypal.  I can't find anything in the 4.7 UI that helps with these kind of recurring contributions.

Comment: If your situation is anything like mine, the only way to find out if a Standing Order payment has been made is by checking your bank statement and hoping that there's a recognisable reference there. In our pre-Civi days I wrote a procedure in MS Access to identify and import those contributions from a downloaded statement file. I'm hopeful that there's a neater solution out there.

Comment: For a neater solution, there's the CiviBanking extension (see https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviBanking) from Systopia but that is probably somewhat heavyweight for a small installation.  But excellent for a user with lots of bank transactions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking a very UK-specific question about direct debit. UK has special rules for direct debit that CiviCRM doesn't know anything about. But the iATS Payments payment processor does support the required workflow and the civicrm extension for iATS Payments does have a dedicated payment processor for that purpose, so that might work for you.

There is some information about how to set it up on this page:

https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm

[2020-06-22 Update: the iATS payments extension has dropped it's UK-specific support code]

Comment: For clarity, in the UK a (Bank) Standing Order functions in a very different way to a Direct Debit.  When a donor agrees to a DD, they effectively give permission to the recipient to take funds from their account as necessary, and amounts may differ each time. A BSO is an instruction to their bank to make a regular transfer, usually of a fixed amount. The recipient is not party to that agreement (although they are usually well aware of it!)

Comment: so was the OP about direct debits or BSO? I just edited the title to make it clearer this was not about recuring credit card details but now wonder if i have used wrong term

Comment: Petednz, I think you have added the wrong term as it says 'standing order' in the body of the question. A standing order (BSO) is initiated by the payee, whereas a direct debit is initiated by the organisation. So I have changed the title again.

Comment: thanks for that Mick